# Actively Tracking object tab stop focus

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, dom, silverlight-5.0

Can someone enlighten me to an efficient way of tracking the tab focus amongst objects in the DOM tree? I thought xaml spy did this but I hadn't used it in quite some time and so far it doesn't appear so, it just allows me to highlight an object and see what it is, but I need something to actively tell me what's receiving focus in the TabIndex.

So for instance I've got a TabControl in a ChildWindow, and in each TabItem there's two phantom tab stops that I'm just not finding. This sort of thing is usually a pretty simple thing to hunt down the culprits and remedy. Except I can't seem to identify what objects are apparently in the tabindex after you've tabbed through everything you would expect to be tabbed through. I even combed through the control templates to make sure the ContentControl's and such had IsTabStop="False" which they do.

This would be a handy thing to know and I must be searching using the wrong verbiage because I would expect this has come up before?

Comment: I have a nice `FocusedElementDebugInfoBehavior` here that helped me in finding annoying phantom tab stops in my code. Attach it to your UI root element, and during runtime when you press a key combination it ouputs the focused element and its ancestors via `Debug.WriteLine`. I answer as soon as the question is no longer put on hold.

Comment: Huh, I didn't expect this to be put on hold since it's a pretty straight forward question, but oh well. @Martin thanks, that sounds handy and would save me from having to do something like the same if you care to share?

Comment: I gladly share, give me a few minutes while I try to figure out how to post it online...maybe I try dotnetfiddle.net?

Comment: ok, sent via email. you can delete your comments now

Comment: @Martin thank ya sir, a beer is owed :)

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, Stackoverflow should definitely have a "send beer" button.